# how to query a database using mongoose in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have written the following method that searches for a user in the database by their email.

```
/**
 * Find a user by providing their email address
 */
DataProvider.prototype.findUserByEmail = function(callback, email) {
console.log("in findUserByEmail");
User.findOne({
    emailAddress : email
}, function(error, user) {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
        callback(error);
    }
    else {
        console.log(user);
        callback(user);
    }
});
};
```

I'm trying to test it with the following:

```
function testFindUserByEmail() {
var expectedEmail = "user@user.com";
data.findUserByEmail(function(user) {
            if (user.emailAddress === expectedEmail) {
                console.log("User found");
            } else {
                console.log("User not found");
            }
    console.log(user);
}, "user@user.com");
console.log("test");
}
```

I get an outout of:
in findUserByEmail
test

It's like User.findOne() isn't getting called and I don't know why.
Other info:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
emailAddress : {
    type : String
},
occupation : {
    type : String
},
token : {
    type : String
},
password : {
    type : String
},
registrationDate : {
    type : Date
},
activated : {
    type : Boolean
}
});

/**
 * Define Model
 */
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
DataProvider = function() {
};
```

Answer (score 1):

did you connected the database,
try: `mongoose.connect('db-uri', function (err) {
        next(err);
    });`

Comment: Yeah, I had. I solved the issue though. Turns out there was a problem with the mongoDb connection. I was getting a 'Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:84' error. Thanks for your answer - it turned me into the right direction of checking my connection